# ActionScript 3 - RangeError: Error #2004 - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I have the following code which loads a sound, 'test.mp3', and then lowers its pitch, also slowing it down. The sound plays correctly at the lower pitch but at the end of the sample, I get this error: 'RangeError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.'. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this problem? Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

```
var sourceSound:Sound = new Sound();
var outputSound:Sound = new Sound();

var urlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest('test.mp3');

sourceSound.load(urlRequest);
sourceSound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundLoaded);

function soundLoaded(event:Event):void {

    outputSound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, processSound);
    outputSound.play();

}

function processSound(event:SampleDataEvent):void {

    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    sourceSound.extract(bytes, 4096);
    var returnBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    bytes.position=0;

    while (bytes.bytesAvailable > 0) {

        returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
        returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
        bytes.position -= 4;
        returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());

    }

    event.data.writeBytes(returnBytes);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by, instead of going back over half the bytes on every iteration, going over all of the bytes every other iteration. So the processSound function now looks like this:

```
function processSound(event:SampleDataEvent):void {

    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    sourceSound.extract(bytes, 4096);
    bytes.position=0;

    var returnBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

    var count:int;

    while (bytes.bytesAvailable > 0) {

        returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
        returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());

        count++;

        if (count%2 === 0) {

            bytes.position-=8;
            returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
            returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());

        }

    }

    event.data.writeBytes(returnBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running an infinite loop and you're incrementing up through the byte array, then back but then forward so you're doing a whole six steps forward, 4 back. I'd change the code here all together get rid of the while loop replace it with a for conditional. I'd have a set sumber of iterations and ensure that the way you're stepping up and down the bytearray does not run you out of the bounds of the array itself, which is probably what's happening here. If possible, access the binary data using the array accessors (bytearray[index]) and iterate with a condition of (i=n; i < bytes.length; ++i).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Any pointers on how I'd get started doing the for loop? As you can probably tell, I'm not too experienced with ActionScript...